# Associated entity with OneToOne mapping coming in as null - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have two entities: TableA and TableB. When I fetch TableA, TableB is always null. What am I doing wrong?
This is how I am getting it:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TableA> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(TableA.class);
Root<TableA> from = criteriaQuery.from(TableA.class);
criteriaQuery.select(from);
```

This is the Query made:

```
select generatedAlias0 from TableA as generatedAlias0
```

TableA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class TableA implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id = null;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private Integer active = null;
    
    private Integer parentId = null;
    
    private String myColA = null;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "parentId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "active", referencedColumnName = "active")}
    )
    @Where(clause = "active=1")
    private TableB TableB = null;

    private Boolean ignorePlanCutoff = null;
}
```

TableB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class TableB implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id = null;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private Integer active = null;
    
    private Integer parentId = null;
    
    private Boolean colB = null;
}
```

Both these entities have composite IDs, not showing that here for brevity.

Comment: Is this Where(clause = "active=1") filter annotation really necessary when the active column is the primary key of the referenced entity? You should not be setting flags as part of an entities ID as you cannot ever change them, and it should be meaningless here where you already have a fk that filters on the specific  TableB. I'd guess this is interfering with your expected results if the referenced TableB isn't active, or has its identity changed.

Comment: @Chris I tried taking it out to no effect...

Comment: Turn on logging and see the SQL generated for these reads, and look at the data you have in the DB; show them in the question if it isn't clear what might be happening. The fact you have 'active' as the ID suggests to me you might be trying to change the id values, which will have issues like this if you try to read things back with any sort of cache (first level cache within an EntityManager as well as secondary/shared caches), as what you get back might not be what you expect from the database. Try forcing an em.refresh(tableA) and try a find by id on the tableB instance you expected to see

Comment: @Chris It seems like the query it makes should be like TableB.parentid = ?, but it is TableB.id = ?. Tried moving these two attributes around with no luck

Comment: Check what is in the row for the parentId value, but it isn't likely being set. I didn't realize this was a backwards relationship - the FK is in the TableB table, and is mapped 'wrong'.  You should have a TableB->TableA OneToOne, with JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName="id"), JoinColumn(name="active", "referencedColumnName = "active", insertable=false, updatable=false). You can then have a reference in TableA->TableB without the join columns defined, using @OneToOne(mappedby="tableA", fetch = FetchType.EAGER).

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much, I put the mappedBy in TableA and JoinColumn in TableB which solved the issue.